# Comparing id of itertools.product

Tags: python

How do you explain the following snippet where I get different results if I call `id` on `product` seperately, but the `id`s are equal if I compare them against each other?

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> id(product("01"))
41401800
>>> id(product(["0", "1"]))
41402080
>>> id(product("01")) == id(product(["0", "1"]))
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference whatsoever, but to explain it ;-):  in your second spelling, both products are temporary objects, destroyed *immediately* after their id is obtained.  "Immediately" is a consequence of CPython's reference counting.  So the memory used for the first product is released before the second product is constructed, and that very same memory *may* get reused for the second product.  There's no guarantee that it will be reused, or that it won't be.  In your example, it so happened that it was reused.

Your first spelling *could* display this behavior too - but it so happens it didn't.

This isn't deep.  It's trivial ;-)

BTW, it's less *likely* you'll get the same ids in the first spelling just because the interpreter has to allocate memory for other stuff between steps; for example, it needs to allocate memory to display "41401800".